# How to add Font Awesome icon to my Angular app

Tags: angular, angular-fontawesome

I am trying to add a certain Font Awesome icon to my Angular app, but it is not working.

I followed these steps:

1. Run `npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome`
2. Update app.module:

`import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';`

`imports: [AngularFontAwesomeModule]`

3. Update `angular.json`:

`"styles": ["node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"]`

This icon is displaying as expected:

```
<i class="fa fa-american-sign-language-interpreting fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
```

But when I try to add the below icon, nothing is appearing:

```
<i class="far fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
```

[This is where](https://fontawesome.com/icons/trash-alt?style=regular) I got this icon from.

Can someone please tell me why this icon isn't appearing, & how I can resolve this?

Comment: Follow this guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: @Reactgular Hi, I followed the installation steps already

Comment: But you're not following the steps. Use the `<fa-icon>` component instead, because it supports tree shaking.

Comment: Typo? Your css class should be “fa” not “far”